# Rails 4 Active Records: Order by position on association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models:

```
class Country
  has_many :competitions
end

class Competition
  belongs_to :country
end
```

Competition class has a position attribute. Admin can sort competitions by position. I want to sort countries with the minimum position of its competitions. I also want to joing competitions with country. How can i achieve that?

I want an output like:

```
X Country: (is at first order because Xcomp1's position is 1)
  Xcomp1 (position: 1)
  Xcomp2 (position: 12)

A Country: 
  Acomp1 (position:2)
  Acomp2 (position:3)

Z Country: (is at last position because minimum position of its competitions are higher than other ones)
  Zcomp1 (position:5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd have to:

```
Country.order("(select min(position) from competitions where competitions.country_id = countries.id) asc")
```

I'm not sure how that syntax holds up across different RDBMSs -- should be good on PostgreSQL and Oracle

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I actually tried order by min keyword but mine was illegal:

Country.order("min(competition.position)")


It works for mysql too. Thanks again :)